# jqgrid : onchange event not working on tab for local grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using grid with below properties

```
cellEdit: true,
    datatype: 'json',
    viewrecords: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    loadonce: true
```

colmodel has one column as :

```
{ name: 'Input', width: 120, editable: true, editoptions: { dataEvents: [
   { type: 'change', fn: function (e) {
            alert('hi');
           }
       },
      ]
    }
}
```

Now when i enter a value in Input and clicks on other cell, the change event fires but when i enter a value and press tab it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem you should use jqGrid [callbacks of cell editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events) like `beforeSaveCell`, `beforeSubmitCell`, `afterSubmitCell` or `afterSaveCell` instead of usage `change` event.